# Malfunctioning fan controller

Tags: fan, desktop-computer, computer-building, case

My PC case has a fan controller on the front with two slide switches that you can use to control fans with 3 pin connectors. You can set each one to high, low or off.

I was trying to install another fan and have it powered straight from the power supply with a molex connector but I accidentally plugged the power into a fan that's connected to the fan controller (it has two connectors).

This caused the PC to turn off and then wouldn't come back on for about 5 minutes. When it did come back on the fan controller wasn't working properly.

Now it will only work if one switch is set to low and the other one is set to high and then the fans on low will run. So you can't have both sets of fans running and you can't run them on high.

I'm wondering if the problem is with the slide switches or something else. If I replace the slide switches do you think that would fix it?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose something like this from the available information.  But my guess is that it is not the switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess: Whatever connection you accidentally made (it's not totally clear from the description what kind of connectors you have and how they work) caused a short or near short with high current flow, which triggered the network safety poweroff, and also destroyed part of the fan controller. Which will now only work if you set the switches to positions which don't use the destroyed part.

Without knowing how everything works, i.e. a schematic where you see what the fan controller consists of and what it does, there's no chance of repairing it.

For starters, you could edit the question with the exact model of your motherboard and case, google for documentation on those, and describe how everything is connected, and how many pins are involved and what voltages they have (measure).